# How to set colors in CandleStickCharts -> MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm face a problem with colors of my chart, this is my chart. Every bar is on color GRAY.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  private void configureChart() {
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(40);
    mChart.animateX(4000);
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(12, false);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
    ArrayList<CandleEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
    float highmax = 1.0500f;
    float highlow = 1.1700f;
    float lowmax = 0.5500f;
    float lowlow = 0.65000f;
    int prog = ((int) (Math.random() + 35));
    for (int i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
        float open = highlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (highmax - highlow);
        float close = lowlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (lowmax - lowlow);
        float high = open + 0.3f;
        float low = close - 0.4f;
        yVals1.add(new CandleEntry(i, high, low, open,
                close));
        String date = String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date()));
        set1 = new CandleDataSet(yVals1, date);
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
        set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
        set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.GRAY);
        set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
        set1.setBarSpace(0.2f);
        set1.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        data = new CandleData(set1);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
        mChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

I trying with add color of decreasing and increasing Color, but i dont know why my every bar is on decreasing color(Gray), like You see on this code.

What i want?

If bar is decreasing i want this bar on color red, but if bar is increasing relative last bar i want this bar on green color.

Are you guys having any idea?

Edit:

Layout

```
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/butonCurrency"
            android:layout_margin="30dp" />

@BindView(R.id.chart)
    CandleStickChart mChart;
```

Edit:
I start a bounty, I'm need help

Here is image what i want with color:
if next bar is higher the color must be green, but if next is lower the color must be red, as You see on image.

[image]

Please look

```
    private void addEntry(boolean start) {
        data = mChart.getData();
        if (set1 == null) {
            set1 = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set1);
        }
        float highmax = 1.0500f;
        float highlow = 1.1700f;
        float lowmax = 0.5500f;
        float lowlow = 0.65000f;
        int prog = 1;

        float last = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

        for (int i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
            float open = highlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (highmax - highlow);
            float close = lowlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (lowmax - lowlow);

            float max = Math.max(open, close);
            if (last < max) { //swap
                float tmp = open;
                open = close;
                close = tmp;
            }
            last = max;

            float high = open + 0.3f;
            float low = close - 0.4f;
            data.addEntry(new CandleEntry(set1.getXMax() + 1, high, low, open,
                    close), 0);

            set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
            set1.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
            set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
            set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
            set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
            set1.setBarSpace(0.2f);


//        int prog = 1;
//        float highmax = 1.0500f;
//        float highlow = 1.1700f;
//        float lowmax = 0.5500f;
//        float lowlow = 0.65000f;
//        for (int i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
//            float open = highlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (highmax - highlow);
//            float close = lowlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (lowmax - lowlow);
//            float high = open + 0.2f;
//            float low = close - 0.3f;
//            data.addEntry(new CandleEntry(set1.getXMax() + 1, high, low, open,
//                    close), 0);
            data.notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.moveViewTo(data.getEntryCount() - 50, 2f, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        }
    }
```

addEntry is working in handler and every 5 sec, he add a new entry

[image]

Comment: Can you post a simple project? This much code is not sufficient.

Comment: It would probably help if added some sample data, and then an image (PhotoShop or GIMP 2) of how you want it to appear.

Comment: Thanks for reply, here is image what i want.

Comment: This code on main post is just creating a chart{xml} and configureChart just give a data to this chart

If You guys want something more, please reply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick solution

The code with the smallest difference from what you have written to what you require is something like the following:

```
private void configureChart() {
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(40);
    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(12, false);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    ArrayList<CandleEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
    float highmax = 1.0500f;
    float highlow = 1.1700f;
    float lowmax = 0.5500f;
    float lowlow = 0.65000f;
    int prog = ((int) (Math.random() + 35));

    float last = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    String date = String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date()));

    for (int i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
        float open = highlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (highmax - highlow);
        float close = lowlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (lowmax - lowlow);

        float max = Math.max(open, close);
        if (last < max) { //swap
            float tmp = open;
            open = close;
            close = tmp;
        }
        last = max;

        float high = open + 0.3f;
        float low = close - 0.4f;
        yVals1.add(new CandleEntry(i, high, low, open, close));
    }
    CandleDataSet set1 = new CandleDataSet(yVals1, date);
    CandleData data = new CandleData(set1);
    mChart.setData(data);

    set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
    set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
    set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
    set1.setBarSpace(0.2f);
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.animateX(4000);
}
```

It gives the following output:

[image: a candlestick chart]

You can see that a decrease from the previous bar to the current bar will show as red while an increase will show as green which is what you wanted.

## Why wasn't the original code working?

In the context of a CandleStickChart, "increasing" means `open <= close`. This is explained in the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/CandleDataSet.html) for `CandleDataSet:setIncreasingColor()`

> Sets the one and ONLY color that should be used for this DataSet when open <= close.

In other words, "increasing" is for bullish stocks and "decreasing" is for bearish stocks. It doesn't mean "increasing with respect to the previous candle". Please see the [Wikipedia article on Candlestick charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) for more information.

[image: a picture of bullish and bearish candles]

*image from Wikipedia article*

Some other problems: a `CandleEntry` represents a single candle on the chart. A group of these is called a `CandleDataSet`. The group of sets (usually just 1 for a `CandleChart`) is called `CandleData`. You can get this information from looking at the tool tips <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd> on Mac. Or looking at the example project in the MPAndroidChart GitHub repo.

*Update:*

After I wrote my answer which was accepted, you updated your question with a new requirement. This new requirement should really be posed as a new question and it's against the rules of the bounty to alter the question substantially after you have posed it. However, I'll try and answer it anyway because I like to help. You want to update your chart with data every 5 sec with an `addEntry` method. First, make sure you understand all the concepts about `DataSet` and `Entry`. Then try and think of some high-level pseudocode. The pseudocode might be something like the following:

1. Look at the last candle
2. `if` the last candle max (open or close) is higher than the current data max (open or close), cause the current candle to be a "decreasing" candle. `else` make the current candle an "increasing" candle.

Number 2 is the most difficult - think about how the code in my original answer does this (clue, it's the part commented "swap").

Here's a snippet to get you started:

```
public void addEntry(float high, float low, float open, float close) {
    CandleData candleData = chart.getData();
    CandleDataSet set1 = candleData.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    float xMax = set1.getXMax();
    CandleEntry lastEntry = set1.getEntryForXPos(xMax);
    CandleEntry currentEntry;
```

Comment: I will accept Your answer now. Its help me so much, but i  have a question about my method AddEntry, becouse if this work every bar is green, Please look at edited post, maybe you will see what is wrong,

THanks so much for help. I need to study your code :)

Comment: I can bounty your answer in 4 hour

Comment: @Rodriquez thanks for the quick upvote and accept. I'll have a look at your other problem

Comment: @Rodriquez I don't understand what the update is about. Are you talking about a compiler error (red lines in Android Studio) or a crash you are getting? If it's a crash, can you post the full stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: No. I have a method addEntry, and that method is add a new Entry, i put it in handler. So every 5 sec i got a new entry in chart, but every entry is on green color.

Comment: @Rodriquez I think you will have to inspect the `CandleEntry` in the chart with the maximum x-value and compare it to the `CandleEntry` you are adding. If it is decreasing, you will have to swap `open` and `close`. I have to do some things now but I'll try and update my answer later on

Comment: As your answer update, u mean that i need t configure this one:

 if (mChart.getXChartMax() < last) {
                float tmp = close;
                open = close;
                close = tmp;
            }else {
                
            }
            last = max;

?

Comment: I gotta go to the supermarket now, but something like that. You want to get the CandleEntry with the highest x-value first. Then get the max of the open and close for that CandleEntry. Then compare with the max open of the open and close for the current Entry.

Comment: Still trying :) once i have a green bars, once i have a red bars, this is no my level with programming, i need to learn more :) i can reward you in 1 hour

Comment: @Rodriquez I'll check again in the morning because it's 10pm here now :-) If you haven't got it by then, I'll probably be able to put some code tomorrow. Although I think if you try very hard you will be able to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @Rodriquez i updated the answer before i go to sleep. i havent had time to test it though. you should be able to finish it yourself

Comment: Yea i done, i rebuild some of you snipchet code everything work perfectly, thanks for help friend

Comment: @Rodriquez you are welcome. Thanks for the bounty. Can you please accept my answer too (green tick) ?

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
private void configureChart() {
        //mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(40);
        mChart.animateX(4000);
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(12, false);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        ArrayList<CandleEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<>();
        float highmax = 1.0500f;
        float highlow = 1.1700f;
        float lowmax = 0.5500f;
        float lowlow = 0.65000f;
        int prog1 = ((int) (Math.random() + 35));
        for (int i = 0; i < prog1; i++) {

            float open = highlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (highmax - highlow);
            float close = lowlow + new Random().nextFloat() * (lowmax - lowlow);
            float high = open + 0.3f;
            float low = close - 0.4f;
            float val = (float) (Math.random() * 40) ;

            boolean even = i % 2 == 0;
            yVals1.add(new CandleEntry(i, val + high, val - low, even ? val + open : val - open, even ? val - close : val + close));
            String date = String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", new java.util.Date()));
            CandleDataSet set1 = new CandleDataSet(yVals1, date);
            set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
            set1.setColor(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80));
            set1.setIncreasingColor(Color.GREEN);
            set1.setIncreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            set1.setDecreasingColor(Color.RED);
            set1.setDecreasingPaintStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            set1.setNeutralColor(Color.BLUE);
            set1.setBarSpace(0.2f);
            set1.setShadowColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            set1.setShadowWidth(0.7f);
            set1.setValueTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            CandleData data = new CandleData(set1);
            mChart.setData(data);
            mChart.invalidate();
            mChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    }
```

In this, you have to specify your `high`, `low` and `open`, `close` value based on your position of your candle stick.

Comment: Hello, this give me totally random chart with random color of bars

Comment: I just set random data, you have to set your data which you want I mean as per your requirement. And here is only one problem whit your code.

Comment: But the problem is when i add the float val, this just destroy my chart, now like u see on photo is that what i want

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to use shadow color. Simply set color to none for shadow. And using colors or color set appropriate colors.

```
CandleDataSet set = new CandleDataSet(..., ...);
set.shadowColor = ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE
set.colors = colors
```